# How use HttpWebResponse and WebResponse in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpwebresponse, webresponse

I'm porting an old C# Shared Lib to a Standard Library. However I'm facing with a lot of `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` and `System.Net.WebResponse` references. It used to exist on .Net Framework 4.5 But I'm not able to find similar in .Net standard.

What can I do to be able to use those?

Comment: Are you using `System.Net.Requests` namespace or `System.Net.Http` namespace?

Comment: @S.Dav,  question edited with this detail

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: ASP NET Core 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually using [`System.Net.Requests`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests/) wich is not available for .NETStandard 1.6 nor for .Net Core.

Try to use the classes in [`System.Net.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) instead.

Or you can install *[System.Net.Requests](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests/)* NuGet package through Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package System.Net.Requests -Version 4.3.0
```

This package contains compatible classes to [`System.Net.Requests`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests/) and can be used as replacement of it.

Comment: According to the NuGet link you specified, it is available in .NET Standard 1.0, so it should be compatible with .NET 4.5. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library